# How can I check out only specified fields when I query the models?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

How can I query the model by constraint some fields, such as I don't want to query out the id, and password.

```
Class AppUser(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=16)
```

When I query it now the situation is:

```
app_users = models.AppUser.objects.all()  # all the fields will be find out.
```

So, how can I check out only specified fields when I query it, I don't want to shows the id and password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `defer()` or `only()`.

Eg: `app_users = models.AppUser.objects.defer('id', 'password')`

would construct an SQL query which would be `SELECT * FROM ....`, but without loading `id` and `password`. The `defer()` is used to avoid loading certain fields.

`app_users = models.AppUser.objects.only('id')`

this would now only load `id`s from the database, meaning `only()` is used to retrieve specific fields from the database. These are `QuerySet` attributes which are used for performance optimisation in Django.

More on [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#defer).

Answer (score 2):

you can use `values` or `values_list`

```
app_users = models.AppUser.objects.all().values('email')
```

or you can use list of fields

```
values = ['username', 'email']
app_users = models.AppUser.objects.all().values(*values)
```

more details [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values)